# Automatically add "..." if text extends certain width, but show it on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do the following, having a `<div>` of certain width, lets say `30%` and than 1 line of text in it, however I want to show `...` if text is to long, also width of the `<div>` will be changing, as it is a responsive design, so `...` should adjust accordingly. But if a person hovers over that `<div>`, it should extend it's width (it will be absolutely positioned, so going out of certain borders is allowed.) and show all text, on the same line.

Example:

```
This is text that fits
```

```
This is text that doesn't fit inside ...
```

```
This is text that doesn't fit inside, but is visible on hover.
```

Not sure if it can be done with pure `HTML` and `CSS` and work cross browser, maybe some overflow hidden backup? or `JQuery`, if it can't be achieved with anything else.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is possible with [pure CSS](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html):

```
#test {
    width: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#test:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qyNUG/

Comment: wow, so simple, didn't know about existence of text-overflow, thanks!

Comment: Hi, noticed interesting thing, if you set a background colour to #text div, it doesn't work on hover http://jsfiddle.net/qyNUG/3/ any ideas how to fix it? even tried setting it to !important, didn't work

Answer (score 5):

This is a css3 version that is based on a pixel width. If you had a container which was a certain size that you wnated this text to work within then you could use width: 100%; to work within it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/RPgaN/2/)

```
<p>This is text that doesn't fit inside, but is visible on hover.</p>


p {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
p:hover {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: The reason I use max-width is so that I can have a transition on the revealing of the text, like so http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/RPgaN/4/

Comment: You could use width in this example but I feel that max-width was more fit for purpose as an element to which a max-width is applied will never be wider than the value specified.